# D3JS: help to create a SVG text element inside a circle using D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a code which draws a different SVG image (countries) when hovering over a list of SVG text elements. I have also created a SVG element where a value inside a object array must be shown. The value depends on the country hovered.

I created a temporary `<p>` element which shows the needed values when hovering on any text element of the country list but what I really need is to create a SVG text element in the middle of the circle which shows the values (currently being shown on a horrible `<p>` element)

The countries svg codes are extremely big so I have just replaced them by a simple svg icon in order to make this question.

I'm using D3js v5 and jquery v3.3.1.

I will highly appreciate any help. Thanks.

```js
  var myGroup = '<g class="iconXY"><path class="st0" d="M15.6,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C13.2,9.7,14.2,10.9,15.6,10.9L15.6,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M18.6,11.6h-1.2l-1.8,5.5l-1.8-5.5h-1.2c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7v13h2.4l1.2,16.4h3.6l1.2-16.4H21v-13C21,12.8,19.9,11.6,18.6,11.6L18.6,11.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M31.9,10.9c1.3,0,2.4-1.2,2.4-2.7c0-1.5-1.1-2.7-2.4-2.7c-1.3,0-2.4,1.2-2.4,2.7C29.5,9.7,30.6,10.9,31.9,10.9L31.9,10.9z"/><path class="st0" d="M39.8,25.2l-3.6-11.6c0,0-0.6-2-2.4-2h-3.6c-1.8,0-2.4,2-2.4,2l-3.6,11.6l1.2,0.7l4.2-9.5l-3.6,14.3h3.6l1.2,13h2.4l1.2-13H38l-3.6-14.3l4.2,9.5L39.8,25.2L39.8,25.2z"/></g>';
    
    var mapData = [
   {"imgSrc":"australia_svg", "code":"AU" , "name":"Australia", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"}, 
   {"imgSrc":"belgium_svg", "code":"BE" , "name":"Belgium", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"}, 
   {"imgSrc":"other_americas_svg", "code":"BR" , "name":"Other Americas", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"canada_svg", "code":"CA" , "name":"Canada", "value":4, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"finland_svg", "code":"FI" , "name":"Finland", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"france_svg", "code":"FR" , "name":"France", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"}, 
   {"imgSrc":"germany_svg", "code":"DE" , "name":"Germany", "value":14, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"india_svg", "code":"IN" , "name":"India", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"ireland_svg", "code":"IE" , "name":"Ireland", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"japan_svg", "code":"JP" , "name":"Japan", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"korea_svg", "code":"KP" , "name":"Korea, Dem. Rep.", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"luxembourg_svg", "code":"LU" , "name":"Luxembourg", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"netherlands_svg", "code":"NL" , "name":"Netherlands", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"norway_svg","code":"NZ" , "name":"New Zealand", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"new_zealand_svg", "code":"NO" , "name":"Norway", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"paraguay_svg", "code":"PY" , "name":"Paraguay", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"saudi_arabia_svg", "code":"SA" , "name":"Saudi Arabia", "value":2, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"singapore_svg", "code":"SG" , "name":"Singapore", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"spain_svg", "code":"ES" , "name":"Spain", "value":1, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"switzerland_svg", "code":"CH" , "name":"Switzerland", "value":6, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"uk_svg", "code":"GB" , "name":"United Kingdom", "value":4, "color":"#BC204B"},
   {"imgSrc":"us_svg", "code":"US" , "name":"United States", "value":4, "color":"#BC204B"}
  ];
  
        var width = 512
        var height = 600
        var radius = 5
   
  var countryWidth = 250
  var countryHeight = 250
 
        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",width)
            .attr("height",height)
            .style("background","#dedede")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform","translate(50,500) rotate(-90)")
  
  var svg2 = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
   .attr("width",countryWidth*1.5)
            .attr("height",countryHeight*1.5)
   .style("background","none")
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","countryHolder")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + countryWidth/3.5 + "," + countryHeight/5 + ") scale(1.5)")
   .html(myGroup); 
  
  var svg3 = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
   .attr("width",countryWidth/2)
            .attr("height",countryHeight/2)
   .style("background","none")
   .attr("class","svg3")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + (-countryWidth*1.2) + "," + (-countryHeight*1.5) + ")")
   
  var circlee = d3.select(".svg3")
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cy","10")
   .attr("cx","10")
   .attr("r","30")
   .attr("fill","#bc204b")
   .attr("class","circle")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + countryWidth/4 + "," + countryHeight/4 + ") scale(1.5)")
  
  var string = d3.select(".circle")
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","statsHolder")
  
   
            var g = svg.selectAll("g")
                  .data(mapData)
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                      return "translate(" + i * 20 + "," + 0+ ")";
                  })

      
            var circles = g.append("circle")
                .attr("cx",0)
                .attr("cy",0)
                .attr("r",radius)
                .attr("fill","#00A3A1")
    .attr("class","circleGroupMember pointer")
                .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
                .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut);

            var labels = g.append("text")
                    .attr("class","countriesText pointer")
                    .style("fill", "black")   
                    .attr("x", 0)           
                    .attr("y", 0)           
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")           
                    .attr("text-anchor", "start") 
                    .text(function(d,i){
                        return mapData[i].name;
                })
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,20) scale(1) rotate(90)")
    .on("mouseover", MouseOverText)
                .on("mouseout", MouseOutText);

   var i 
   var circleGroupMember = $(".circleGroupMember");
  
   for(i = 0; i<circleGroupMember.length; i++){
    circleGroupMember[i].setAttribute("id",mapData[i].imgSrc)
   }
  
 /*-------------------------Mouse over text function-----------------------*/ 
  
   function MouseOverText(){
       d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(8800)
    .style("font-weight","bold") 
    .attr("fill", "#00338D")
    
  for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++){
     if(mapData[i].name == $(this).html()){
      $(".statsP").html(mapData[i].value + "%" ).css({"font-size": "30px"})

     }
    }
     
    if($(this).html() == "United States"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "India"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
  
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Switzerland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "United Kingdom"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Canada"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
     
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Japan"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
   
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Australia"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html () == "Saudi Arabia"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Belgium"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Finland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() =="France"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Germany"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Ireland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
      
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Korea, Dem. Rep."){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Luxembourg"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Netherlands"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "New Zealand"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Norway"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)

     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Paraguay"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     else if($(this).html() == "Spain"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(myGroup)
 
     }
     
   }
  
  /*-------------------------Mouse out text function-----------------------*/
   function MouseOutText(){
     d3.select(this)
    .transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(8800) 
    .style("font-weight","normal")
    .attr("fill", "#000")   
   }
  
  /*-------------------------Mouse Over Dot function-----------------------*/
  
            function handleMouseOver(d, i) { 
                d3.select(this)
     .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .duration(8800)
     .attr("fill", "#C6007E")
     .duration(150)
     .attr("r", function(){
      return radius * 2
     })
    
    $(this).next().css({fill:"#00338D", fontWeight:"bold"})
    
     if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "United States"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(us_svg)
     }
     else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "India"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(india_svg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "United Kingdom"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(uk_svg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Canada"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(canada_svg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Japan"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(japan_svg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Australia"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(australia_svg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Saudi Arabia"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(saudi_arabia)
     }
     else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Belgium"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(belgium)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Finland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(finland)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "France"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(france)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Germany"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(germany)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Ireland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(ireland)
     }
        else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Korea, Dem. Rep."){
      $(".countryHolder").html(south_korea)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Luxembourg"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(luxembourg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Netherlands"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(netherland)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "New Zealand"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(new_zealand)
     }
    else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Norway"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(south_korea)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Paraguay"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(luxembourg)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Spain"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(netherland)
     }
         else if($(this).next()[0].innerHTML == "Switzerland"){
      $(".countryHolder").html(switzerland)
     }
    
    console.log(this.id)

   };

  /*-------------------------Mouse out  Dot function-----------------------*/
  
     function handleMouseOut(d, i) { 
                d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .attr("fill", "#00A2A9")
     .attr("r", function(){
      return radius 
     })
      
      $(this).next().css({fill:"#000", fontWeight:"normal"})
   };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="statsDiv">
  <p class="statsP"></p>
 </div>
 <div id="countryDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to place a `g` and subsequently a `text` as a child of the `circle`?

Comment: Yes, exactly.   But I don't know how to deal with the chaining syntax, every time I try to append a `text` it gets appended anywhere else. I'd like to know how to append a `text` just in the middle of the `circle` so that I can   display on it the data currently being displayed in the `p` tag. I'm trying to try this: 

 `var string = d3.select(".circle")
   .append("g")
   .attr("class","statsHolder")
   .append("text")
   .html("this is a test")` 

but doesn't work

Comment: That happens here `$(".statsP").html(mapData[i].value + "%" ).css({"font-size": "30px"})`

Comment: The `g` has to be the parent of both the `circle` and `text` - `d3.select(".circle") .append("g")` attempts to place a `g` within a `circle` (circles with class `circle`), this approach will not work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified what you have into what i think you're trying to achieve. I don't think there is any need to use jquery for what you are doing.

```js
const mapData = [{
    "imgSrc": "australia_svg",
    "code": "AU",
    "name": "Australia",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "belgium_svg",
    "code": "BE",
    "name": "Belgium",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "other_americas_svg",
    "code": "BR",
    "name": "Other Americas",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "canada_svg",
    "code": "CA",
    "name": "Canada",
    "value": 4,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "finland_svg",
    "code": "FI",
    "name": "Finland",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "france_svg",
    "code": "FR",
    "name": "France",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "germany_svg",
    "code": "DE",
    "name": "Germany",
    "value": 14,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "india_svg",
    "code": "IN",
    "name": "India",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "ireland_svg",
    "code": "IE",
    "name": "Ireland",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "japan_svg",
    "code": "JP",
    "name": "Japan",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "korea_svg",
    "code": "KP",
    "name": "Korea, Dem. Rep.",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "luxembourg_svg",
    "code": "LU",
    "name": "Luxembourg",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "netherlands_svg",
    "code": "NL",
    "name": "Netherlands",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "norway_svg",
    "code": "NZ",
    "name": "New Zealand",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "new_zealand_svg",
    "code": "NO",
    "name": "Norway",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "paraguay_svg",
    "code": "PY",
    "name": "Paraguay",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "saudi_arabia_svg",
    "code": "SA",
    "name": "Saudi Arabia",
    "value": 2,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "singapore_svg",
    "code": "SG",
    "name": "Singapore",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "spain_svg",
    "code": "ES",
    "name": "Spain",
    "value": 1,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "switzerland_svg",
    "code": "CH",
    "name": "Switzerland",
    "value": 6,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "uk_svg",
    "code": "GB",
    "name": "United Kingdom",
    "value": 4,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  },
  {
    "imgSrc": "us_svg",
    "code": "US",
    "name": "United States",
    "value": 4,
    "color": "#BC204B"
  }
];

// Setup
const width = 512
const height = 600
const radius = 5

// Select the placeholder for the svg,
// append and style the svg
const svg = d3.select("#svgDiv")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("background", "#dedede")

// Select the placeholder for the list of countries
// & append an empty list 
const countryList = d3.select("#countryDiv")
  .append("ul")

// Bind data to the list and append an item for each data point
const countryItem = countryList
  .selectAll("li")
  .data(mapData)
  .enter()
  .append("li")
  .html(d => d.name)
  .on("mouseover", mouseOverTextHandler)

// Append a group which will house your circle and text
const circleG = svg.append("g")

// Append a circle & style it
circleG.append("circle")
  .attr("r", "50")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("cx", "50")
  .attr("cy", "50")

// Append text and align it to the circle sibling
const circleText = circleG.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 50)
  .attr("dx", 50)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")

// Handle our mouseover event with the relevant data point
function mouseOverTextHandler(d, i) {
  circleText.text(d.name)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="countryDiv"></div>
<div id="svgDiv"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/XPjWyM)